# Photoshop CS5 using Polygon Tool for making star size not adjustable

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes, resize, cs5

I'm trying to create an 6-sided star shape with the polygon tool.selecting star in Polygon Options, This is not a problem, but if I want fixed radius there is a option for giving values for radius...i want it to be adjustable in canvas by click and drag  to Adjust the radius of the star..i am not getting wheather there is any option for Click and drag to adjust radius star using Polygon tool.....

Is there an  option which I have to adjust?

i want this star act to be custom shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photoshop contains no support for adjusting the inset radius of a star polygon while dragging.